# Azure Single Container is not mounting volumes

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

We have this Web App running as a docker Single Container that needs to access a storage.

I have successfully created and mapped the storage to my Web App:

[image]

As we can see in the command printed in the log, Azure is not adding my mapped paths as volumes in the `docker run` command:

```
docker run -d -p 8179:80 --name <hidden_for_security> -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=true -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=<hidden_for_security> -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=<hidden_for_security> -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=<hidden_for_security> -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 <hidden_for_security> startup.sh
```

We have it working for Docker Compose (Preview), there we can add volumes in the `yaml`, however I don't want to use compose as I have only one single container.

Why is Azure not adding my volume to Docker? Is it restricted to Docker Compose?

Comment: What do you mean to access the storage from the your code?

Comment: @CharlesXu I removed the text to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no matter if it shows the volumes mount in the docker run command or not, but it does really work for you. And it shows the volumes as environment variables like this:

[image]

You can set the volumes in the Path Mappings of the Web App configuration, or set it via the [Azure CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/how-to-serve-content-from-azure-storage#link-storage-to-your-web-app-preview). The docker-compose file is not the only way.

Comment: I found it on the Kodo interface, but how can I use these variables in my code to read/write data to the storage? I want to access as a mapped volume, not using the SDK...

Comment: @EvandroPomatti When the mount is OK, you just need to access the mount path and read/write data in the mount path. It also means read/write data in the storage container that you mount to the web app.

Comment: @EvandroPomatti Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: I don't know what we were doing wrong before, but I created a fresh new project to test it and indeed it worked. I documented my example [here](https://github.com/evandropomatti/singlecontainer-storage) for anyone that wants to use it as a reference.